# How to only ask for variable one time when intializing a class multiple times (python)

Tags: python, oop, parent-child

```
inc_inp = 0
class Budget:
    def __init__(self,inc_inp = 0):
        if inc_inp < 1:
            self.monthly_income = int(input("Enter monthly income after taxes: "))
            inc_inp += 1



    def deposit(self, dep_amt):
        pass
    
    def withdraw(self, wth_amt):
        pass


class Wants(Budget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(self.monthly_income)

class Needs(Budget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(self.monthly_income)

inc = Needs()
inc2 = Wants()
inc3 = Needs()
```

This gives the result:
Enter monthly income after taxes: 2000
2000
Enter monthly income after taxes: 2000
2000
Enter monthly income after taxes: 2000
2000
(I entered 2000)

I am trying to figure out a way to only ask for monthly_income one time when the class is initialized (i know that if statement doesn't work because it is set to 0 every time the class is initialized, it just makes my question a little more clear)
I want to be able to use the monthly income in my sub classes without having to run a specific method from the parent class (if that makes sense?!) Any advice is much appreciated

Comment: sorry for the way the output is formatted, shouldve put that in the code section. still new to stack overflow. also misspelled withdrawal lol

Comment: It already is asking once when the class is initialized. You are initializing the class three times, so it asks three times.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yes, but is it possible to only ask for it one time and have the child classes inherit the input when they are initialized? (even if not directly possible, is there a good work around?

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You don't need a workaround for anything, you need to rethink your entire approach. From the global `inc_inp` that serves no purpose to the equally pointless `inc_inp += 1` and the creation of new instances that don't do anything, I'd say you have to go back to your instructional materials and review how classes and scope work.

Comment: you can make the init of budget get the var monthly_income and set it as property, then ask the monthly_income before instance the objects. with that variable in it

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 please read the full post before responding. I state that I understand why that if statement doesn't work, i feel it just makes my question easier to understand.

Comment: That if statement has nothing to do with anything and just takes you further from [mcve].

Comment: You do realize that as soon as you want to keep track of two separate budgets for two separate people it won't work, right? This is fundamentally the wrong way to solve the problem.

Comment: I agree with  @TigerhawkT3 in that last one, cant Wants() and Need be methods of the original class?

Answer (score 1):

You can make `inc_inp` a class variable, that way it will be shared between all class/subclass instances.

```python
class Budget:

    inc_inp = 0

    def __init__(self, inc_inp=0):
        if Budget.inc_inp < 1:
            Budget.monthly_income = int(input("Enter monthly income after taxes: "))
            Budget._inc_inp += 1

    def deposit(self, dep_amt):
        pass

    def withdraw(self, wth_amt):
        pass


class Wants(Budget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(self.monthly_income)


class Needs(Budget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(self.monthly_income)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    inc = Needs()
    inc2 = Wants()
    inc3 = Needs()
```

output

```bash
Enter monthly income after taxes: 6
6
6
6
```

Comment: Multiple instances are almost certainly not the way to go in the first place.

Comment: I can't understand why this works that way. why is self.monthly_income being the same?

Comment: @UlisesBussi - That's how variable names are looked up. If it can't find an instance variable with that name, it checks for a class variable with that name.